# How to deploy Express app on surge.sh

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have Express app, and I have index.ejs file instead of index.html and I can't deply it on surge (page not found). I use 'surge' command in project directory and than I go to the domain where it was published but my project doesn't run there. How should I deploy it? Please help me, I need to do it right now [image: my project]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Surge.sh](https://surge.sh/) is for serving static files (html,css,media..etc). Since **ejs** is a server side rendering template engine it can't be served using surge.sh.

Note: You can upload node apps to Heroku for hosting.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to rename somehow to .html to make it work? Could you send me a link how can I deploy this .ejs to heroku plz?

Comment: For hosting NodeJS apps on heroku checkout this [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs). And please make the answer verified so that it will be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have learned express, you can also learn Svelte. its a React/Vue like framework that compiles everything into a simple html/css/js  site that you can then deploy to your favorite static hoster like surge.sh or even  github pages

Answer (score 0):

You can't deploy the Nodejs website on surge.sh as these services do not support server-side rendering like handlebars, ejs or pug, etc.

Vercel, netlify also do not support templating engines. However, you can use openode.io as an alternative, or maybe digitlocean under their app platform.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try to bundle the project and then use surge to publish it. I am not aware of any tool that can do that for you automatically, it might require manual setting.

Check this article:
https://morioh.com/p/c6e73ed575bb